# Recreate a database using existing php code

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I have an old website which was coded over an extended period of time but has been inactive for 3 or so years. I have the full PHP source to the site, but the problem is I do not have a backup of the database any longer. I'm wondering what the best solution to recreating the database would be? It is a large site so manually going through each PHP file and trying to keep track of which tables are referenced is no small task. I've tried googling for the answer but have had no luck. Does anyone know of any tools that are available to help extract this information from the PHP and at least give me the basis of a database skeleton? Otherwise, has anyone ever had to do this? Any tips to help me along and possibly speed up the process? It is a mySQL database I'm trying to use.

Comment: Can you post an example of a file you want to add to the database?

Comment: He don't want to add a file. He want to reverse engineering a database from code. But with the information provided we can only guess how php access the database.

Comment: This is going to be a problem. Even if you can extract the items from the code, you're never going to get the full database picture given table-level IDs, key constraints, look-up tables, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to get the site back to a functional state or would it be better to recode the site and reuse what PHP I can?

Comment: I would advice you to just run the site, and it will tell you that database, table, row does not exists. Then you can create them as you go along

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it:

Write a subset of SQLi or whatever interface was used to access the DB to intercept all DB accesses.
Replace all DB accesses with the dummy version of yours.

The basic idea is to emulate the DB so that the PHP code runs long enough to activate the various DB accesses, which in turn will allow you to analyze the way the DB is built and used.

From within these dummy functions:

- print the SQL code used
- regenerate just enough dummy results to let the rest of the code run, based on the tables and fields mentioned in the query parameters **and** the PHP code that retrieves them (you won't learn much from a `SELECT *`, but you can see what fields the PHP code expects to get from it)
- once you have understood enough of the DB structure, recreate the tables and let the original code work on them little by little
- have the previous designer flogged to death for not having provided a way to recreate the DB programatically

Answer (score 0):

There are currently two answers based on the information you provided.

1) you can't do this
PHP is a typeless language. you could check you sql statements for finding field and table names. but it will not complete. if there is a `select * from table`, you can't see the fields. so you need to check there php accesses the fields. maybe by name or by index. you could be happy if this is done by name, because you can extract the name of the fields. finally the data types will missing. also missing: where are is an index on, what are primary keys, constrains etc.

2) easy, yes you can!
because your php is using a modern framework with contains a orm. this created the database for you. a meta information are included in the php classes/design.
just check the manual how to recreate the database.